# Days of week by names of planets?

Tags: scripture, rituals

Is there any significance of Hindu days of week named by planets?

And that each day, people are suggested to do certain activities to please the planet god, such as Shani?

Also, do the Hindu days of week really align with Gregorian days of week. That is, is Somwar really Monday, or some other Gregorian day?

Comment: these informations are available on wikipedia

Answer (score 4):

The english word hour has its' origins in the sanskrit word hora. Brihat Parashara hora shastra is one of the ancient jyotish texts which by the name itself proves the antiquity of the word hora. Jyotish shastra also says that there are 24 horas (hours) in a day. The only difference between hora and hour is that hora starts at the time of sun rise and continues for 60 minutes. The names of the days arise from the first hora. Hence on Monday ( Somvar) the first hora is of the moon or chandra and so on. The horas of a single day are spaced in the followin manner:
On a Sunday the respective horas would be
Surya - Shukra - budha - chandra - shani - guru - mangal - surya......
If you carry on in this series, the first hora starting at the sunrise next day would automatically come as chandra. The Hindu days tally with the Gregorian days.
Sun - Surya -ravivar
Moon - Chandra - somvar
Saturn -Shani - shanivar
Tues,(Tiw: german God of war)
Wednes (Translation of Latin mercury)
Thurs (Translation of Latin Jovis - Jupiter)
Fri ( Translation of Latin veneris - Venus).

Comment: Hi Ravin. Why are the names of horas based on names of planets/sun/moon? Surya - Shukra - budha - chandra - shani - guru - mangal - surya

Comment: It is for the need of a greater accuracy. Broadly giving the names of planets for a full day and then further dividing the day into horas. Just like a janma lagna kundali which divides the full sky of 360 degrees into 12 rashis of 30 degress each and navamansh kundali which further divides 30 degrees by 9. It is also used in the muhurtas. For example if you have to worship a planet, it is to be done on either on the day of that planet or next best on the hora of the planet on any other day.