# Why are the days of the week named the way they are?

Tags: explanation, planets

I understand that Ravivar is named after the sun god and that the rest of the days of the week are named after one planet or the other, but that means only 6 planets have days named after them.

Why did other planets *not* get names of days after themselves?

I don't mean to sound rude but it just seems like some of the gods were more preferred over others for some reason that I can't understand (nobody around me has been able to decode this mystery for me yet).

Why did other planet gods not get days named after them?

Comment: The term that's used in jyotiṣa is *graha*, and there are 9 *grahas* accepted, these are *Sūrya* (Sun), *Candra* (Moon), *Budha* (Mercury), *Śukra* (Venus), *Maṅgala* (Mars), *Br̥haspati* (Jupiter), *Sani* (Saturn), *Rāhu* and *Ketu*. 
*Graha* is translated as planet often, but it's not the right translation because even Sun and Moon are *grahas*. *Rāhu* and *Ketu* are *chāyā grahas*, these are not real planets, but actually mathematical points. As for Uranus, and Neptune, they weren't discovered in ancient times, so they aren't a part of *jyotiṣa*

Comment: Thus, there are only 9 *grahas*, Earth of course isn't technically a *graha* in the sense of *jyotiṣa* because it is after all the place from where you observe the space. We didn't have artificial satellites in ancient times. 
You have 7 days in a week, and these are dedicated to the 7 deities associated with the *grahas*, *Rāhu* and *Ketu* of course won't be included due to them being just mathematical points at which the orbit of Moon around earth cuts the orbit of earth around Sun.

Comment: The concept of the 7-day week with each day named in honour of a planet is completely alien to Hindu astrology. It was introduced in the Indian subcontinent by Greeks alongside Alexander. The concept made it's way into Hindu society through the treatise Yavanajataka, which incorporated Greek elements into jyotisha. Similarly after Muslim conquest of Sindh, Hindu astrologers adopted the Arabic notion of varshaphala through Tajikanilakanthi

Comment: @AnubrataBit - what is source for your claim that weekdays are alien ? the word panchanga - or 5 angas - explicitly has vara (week day) as one of them. many kalpa sutras (another vedanga) which form basis for all smritis detail which week-days to not to certain things

Comment: @mar If you see the description of the units of time given in the Puranas, you can clearly see that the concept of a 7-day week is missing in them. Brihatsamhita doesn't mentions about any method to determine of the day of the week on a random day.

Comment: yes we go from day(tithi) directly to paksha to masa skipping vara.. but that is only because the universe time runs on 360 days/year cycle, not 365.25 solar. it is highly unlikely that kalpa sutras would specify which days of the week to take oil bath (saturday for men, friday for women), if vara was not part of ancient panchang.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Days of week by names of planets?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33840/days-of-week-by-names-of-planets)